# Releasing a Video in Video Causes InvalidStateException

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I created an intro video that, once completed, moves onto the menu activity. I figured it would be good to release the video at that time to free up resources, but doing so causes a `java.lang.InvalidStateException`. Below is the completion code:

```
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
{
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        mp.release();
        startActivity(new Intent(menu));
    }
});
```

I have no idea what's wrong with this.

Comment: check the state of the media player before you do release

Comment: Shouldn't the state be...PlaybackCompleted? I mean, what other state would it be in if this method activates?